# How to transfer a chart from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

This function creates a word doc, saves and closes it, but is failing when I attempt to reopen. It says this at the remote call doesn't work. What is the proper practice for reopening a word doc? Or is it unnecessary to close and open again? It appears there is difficulty with communication between word and excel.

```
Sub tester()
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim appendDate As String
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wordApp.Visible = True

    appendDate = "Y"
    fName = "robot"

    If appendDate = "Y" Or appendDate = "y" Then
        fName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fName & "-" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd-hhmm") & ".docx"
    Else
        fName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fName & ".docx"
    End If

    wordApp.Documents.Add.SaveAs2 fileName:=fName
    wordApp.Documents.Close
    wordApp.Application.Quit
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName:=fPath, readOnly:=False)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    wordDoc.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement:=wdInLine

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you need to create an object again before you use `Set wordDoc`  since you are quitting the application right before?

Comment: It is unnecessary to close and open again in your case. Simply work with the object and then close it in the end

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

```
Option Explicit

Const wdFormatXMLDocument As Integer = 12

Sub tester()
    Dim wordApp As Object, wordDoc As Object
    Dim appendDate As String, FName As String

    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    wordApp.Visible = True

    appendDate = "Y"
    FName = "robot"

    If UCase(appendDate) = "Y" Then  '<~~ Unsure of this as you are already setting the value of Y
        FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FName & "-" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd-hhmm") & ".docx"
    Else
        FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FName & ".docx"
    End If

    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    wordApp.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=0, Placement:=0

    wordDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=FName, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument

    wordDoc.Close (False)

    wordApp.Quit

    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information. I tried this and got an error "word app has stopped working" when this line runs: `wordApp.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement:=wdInLine`

Comment: Hmm. I'm running version 2010 on windows 7. Would that mean I need to change anything there?

Comment: nope :) BTW i tested it in Excel 2013/Win8.1 64 bit

Comment: It works when I run it inside a small text workbook. Wonder why it isn't scaling up properly. Maybe too slow. Anyway, that's another thing I need to do. But also, how would I paste it as an object, not an image? (as in a chart that can be edited within the word doc if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Since you quit the Word.Application then there's no more `wordApp`, so `Documents.Open` has no environment in which to execute.

If you want to open a file at any point, directly, without first starting the application you can use `GetObject`:

Set wordDoc = GetObject(FName)

If you need to address the Word.Application at a later point, after using GetObject to open the file:

```
Set wordApp = wordDoc.Application
```